# Scala: replace char at position i in String

Tags: string, scala, binary

I have an initial String (binary) looking like this :

`val mask = "00000000000000000000000000000000"` of length 32

Additionally, I have a list of positions i (0 <= i <= 31) at which I want the mask to have value 1.

For instance `List(0,12,30,4)` should give the following result :

`mask = "10001000000010000000000000000010"`

How can I do this efficiently in scala ?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A naive approach would be to fold over the positions with zero element 'mask' and successively update the char at the given position:

```
List(0,12,30,4).foldLeft(mask)((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1'))
```

- Daniel

Comment: Good to hear :) I'm curious how the 'view' based solution performs that @Archeg suggested. My solution copies the whole mask on each update (here: 4 times). Using a view, the write operations are lazily deferred until the mkString call. There will be also some overhead regarding intermediate object creation within the view and mkString traversal of the mask elements. I think the memory performance should be better with views. However, the garbage collector should remove unused mask copies without too much effort. The time performance depends on how efficient the string copy is.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the most efficient way I can think of to do this is the same as you'd do it in any other (not functional) programming language:

```
val mask = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
val l = List(0, 12, 30, 4)
val sb = new StringBuilder(mask)
for (i <- l) { sb(i) = '1' }
println(sb.toString)
```

This should actually be more efficient than Daniel answer, but I'd prefer Daniel's due to clarity. Still you've asked for the most efficient way

**Updated**

Ok, I think this should be more or less efficient and FP-style - the trick is to use views:

```
val view : SeqView[Char, Seq[_]] = (mask: Seq[Char]).view
println(List(0,12,30,4).foldLeft(view)((s, i) => s.updated(i, '1')).mkString)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked—but I have to wonder why you're using a String. There's a very efficient data structure for storing this type of information, called a `BitSet`.

If you're using a `BitSet`, then setting the bits corresponding to a list of integers is trivial.

If you want a mutable `BitSet`:

```
scala.collection.mutable.BitSet.empty ++= List(0,12,30,4)
```

If you want an immutable `BitSet`:

```
scala.collection.immutable.BitSet.empty ++ List(0,12,30,4)
```

Comment: This looks handy indeed ! But I have to work with 32bits long masks to perform a SimHash algorithm.